# How to JOIN Tables on the basis of CLOB column in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g, clob

I need to make `JOIN` between 2 Tables on the basis of a `CLOB` column.

Please suggest what will be the best approach to do the same?

Maybe this is not the best implementation in oracle, However, in the current situation only common `column` between both tables has a datatype `CLOB`.

Any suggestions can help.

Comment: Would it be possible to restructure your database design and add constraint columns to your tables, then extract the necessary data from the `CLOB` fields into the new field? Also, I guess it should be asked... what is the content of your `CLOB` fields? Is it `XML` or just various `VARCHAR` data?

Comment: It is `VARCHAR` data and length are greater than 4000 CHAR and restructuring is not possible at least currently.

Comment: Joining two CLOB columns using the following condition is possible: `dbms_lob.compare(table1.clob_col, table2.clob_col) = 0`

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 Ok, Thanks let me check

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 I tried to use this nut query is taking too much time.`SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM T1 JOIN T2
ON dbms_lob.compare(T1.COL1, T2.COL2) = 0;
`  Both T1 and T2 contains 1000 rows and matching rows are also 1000.

Comment: *query is taking too much time* - this is expected! You are making a *cartesian join* with a filter. Your only chance to get acceptable performance is to *add a new column containing e.g. a hash code of the clob* and to use it in the join.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Yes, You are right, I am trying same now.

Comment: Apart from cartesian join, Query will take time in context switching. So it is not a good idea to join based on clob column.

Comment: Ask Tom has an older thread on this: [LINK](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=equality-predicate-on-clob)